# visual studio C# как установить zip из github

Tags: c#, github

скачал например [библиотеку](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp) с гитхаба. как добавить ее в проект на c#?

Comment: Либо собираете и полученную .dll добавляете в проект, либо добавляете в свой `sln` существующий проект, выбрав там исходники данной библиотеки, ну и в нужном проекте подключаете эти исходники. Ну а вообще там есть NuGet...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно выполнить вот эту команду в PM Console.

`Install-Package WebSocketSharp -Pre`

Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console - в самой Visual Studio